# Pyspark: Implement lambda function and udf from Python to Pyspark

Tags: python, apache-spark-sql, user-defined-functions, pyspark

I have a dataframe that I am applying a lambda function to to copy over a row value based on the values of a column.

In Pandas it looks like this:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'lkey': ['foo', 'bar', 'baz', 'foo'],
                    'value': ['one', 'two', 'three', 'five']})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'rkey': ['foo', 'bar', 'baz', 'foo'],
                    'value': ['five', 'six', nan, nan]})

new_df = df1.merge(df2, how='left', left_on='lkey', right_on='rkey')

  lkey value_x rkey value_y
0  foo     one  foo    five
1  foo     one  foo     NaN
2  bar     two  bar     six
3  baz   three  baz     NaN
4  foo    five  foo    five
5  foo    five  foo     NaN


def my_func(row):
        if not row['value_y'] in [nan]:
            row['value_x'] = row['value_y']
        return row


applied_df = new_df.apply(lambda x: my_func(x), axis=1)


  lkey value_x rkey value_y
0  foo    five  foo    five
1  foo     one  foo     NaN
2  bar     six  bar     six
3  baz   three  baz     NaN
4  foo    five  foo    five
5  foo    five  foo     NaN
```

How would I do something similar in Pyspark?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

df1.withColumnRenamed("value","value_x")\
    .join(df2.withColumnRenamed("value","value_y"),F.col("lkey")==F.col("rkey"),'left')\
    .withColumn("value_x", F.when(F.col("value_y").isNotNull(),F.col("value_y")).otherwise(F.col("value_x"))).show()


#+----+-------+----+-------+
#|lkey|value_x|rkey|value_y|
#+----+-------+----+-------+
#| bar|    six| bar|    six|
#| foo|   five| foo|   five|
#| foo|    one| foo|   null|
#| foo|   five| foo|   five|
#| foo|   five| foo|   null|
#| baz|  three| baz|   null|
#+----+-------+----+-------+
```